# $.ajax request fails for first call on page load

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax

I have code snippet where I am pulling all the configs from back-end Node server through `$.ajax`. But when I hit My page first time, I do not get the response, where as When I check the log on node server, I do see the status for the request as 200 Ok. But I refresh the page twice or thrice I get the response properly.

Below is my code:

```
var appConfig = getConfig();
function setAppConfig(){
    var url = env.NEW_SERVER_URL + '/api/client/getConfig/carrier/';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: url,
        success: function (response) {
            //   console.log(response);
            var configData = JSON.stringify(response);
            sessionStorage.setItem('config', configData);
            return true;
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log("some error in connection with server");
            return false;
        }
    });
}

function getConfig(){
    var appConfig = "";
    // console.log(fetchFromSession('config'));
    if(fetchFromSession('config') !== null){
        appConfig = JSON.parse(fetchFromSession('config'));
    }else{
        if(setAppConfig()){
            appConfig = JSON.parse(fetchFromSession('config'));
        }else{
            console.log('Something went wrong in pullling the configs');
        }
    }
    return appConfig;
}
```

**Node Server Code to respond the get request:**

```
exports.config = ((req, res,next) => {
    let carrier = req.params.carrier;
    logger.info("getConfig started", {carrier: carrier});

     if(carrier){
          var msg = require(path.join('./../../../config/',carrier,'/config.json'));
          logger.info("Response for getScripts", {carrier: carrier, response: msg});
          res.send(msg);
     }
})
```

This script is loaded first on the page and all the dependent scripts are marked `defer` to wait for it to get loaded

Questions:

- What is wrong with my code?
- Why does it doesnt work first time but works on refreshing the page after that?
- what do I need to do to get the successful response on first load itself?

Comment: There's no point in using `return true` and `return false` in the callback functions, nothing uses the return values.

Comment: You set `contentType: 'application/json'` but you don't have a `data:` option with the JSON data.

Comment: @Barmar it would be great if you can help me connect your above reported points as the reasoning to the problem I am facing.. because anyways my code works on second or third refresh

Comment: You don't seem to understand that AJAX is asynchronous. You're not waiting for the first AJAX call to complete before you call `fetchFromSession()`.

Comment: That makes sense.. I was having that vibe.. but the thing is how can I control the complete script file loading to wait for ajax call to get completeted? as the fetchfromsession is beig called in the next dependent file.

Comment: you need to call `fetchFromSession()` in the `success:` function of AJAX, or use promises.

Comment: See the duplicate question I linked to for lots of information on this.

Comment: @Barmar i used the promise.. but the thing when My ajax request get resioved after the next scripts file loaded which already uses the parameters and hence it throws me an error

Comment: @Barmar as per provided link, I have used Promises, but I got stuck to other issue, Please navigate here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49917088/184814

Answer (score 0):

please try to use this using `POST` method

LIke

`$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        cache: false,`

Comment: any specific reason behind using POST? By the way I am trying to get data and hence its actually a get request